# How do I create a workflow that creates multiple nodes?

Tags: 8, nodes, forms

I'm recreating my pages in Drupal 8 for a platform upgrade. One thing I've identified for this upgrade is the need for a workflow that creates multiple nodes before it's actually finished. If a user creates node of type A, it automatically creates a second node of Type be and auto-fills an entity reference field with whatever nid Node A was given. I'm HOPING this is something I Can create easily, through a form builder or something like that.

I'm not sure what the best option is for this, but I do need to find a way to simplify this workflow. I think I'll need rules a part of it, but I'm not sure at all one way or the other.

Comment: create node a, on save/submit create also node b with reference to a,  is that what you want ?

Comment: Pretty much yes. I'm basically setting it up for a story archive, where Node A is the front page that contains all the story meta-data, and Node B is Chapter 1. I want to prefile Node B with the Entity Reference information for Node A, and Preset the chapter field I use for organization as 1. 

I basically recreated the book module in Entity References and Views in Drupal 7. Now I'm recreating that work in Drupal 8 and am addressing issues I discovered since I originally did this.

Comment: One place to start would be `hook_node_insert`.

Comment: That sounds like a custom module though. Do you think that this would require a custom module? I'm starting to wonder if maybe it could be handled through Rules or something of that nature. I'm not sure yet, but is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with.  Create a custom module and in your `MODULENAME.module` file implement `hook_form_alter` to add a custom submit handler `MODULENAME_add_story`

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  // if creating node of type A (article is machine name)
  if($form_id == 'node_article_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MODULENAME_add_story';
  }  
}
```

In the custom submit function create the referenced node and save the reference on the original node

```
function MODULENAME_add_story($form, $form_state) {

  $article = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  $aid = $article->id();
  $uid = $article->getOwnerId(); 

  // Create node of type B (story is machine name)    
  $story = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create([
    'type'        => 'story',
    'title'       => 'New auto created story new',
    'uid' => $uid,
    //set other fields
  ]);
  $story->save();    

  //set the reference and save
  $article->field_stories[] = ['target_id' => $story->id()];
  $article->save();
}
```

So when you create node of type `article` a node of type `story` is also created and referenced from `article`.